# How can you get access to the Web API FileSystem object?

Tags: javascript, html, filesystems, sandbox

More specifically, how can you get access to the Web API FileSystem object on-demand in a way that is cross-browser compatible?

[MDN describes two ways to get access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem): The first by using `window.requestFileSystem()`. The second with a file system entry object.

The problem with the first approach is that, [elsewhere in the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestFileSystem), it says that feature has been deprecated. It seems to be only supported on Google Chrome.

The second approach requires having a file system 'entry' object. I would like to be able to create, persist, and alter folders and files on-demand in the FileSystem's virtual drive within the browser sandbox. That means, without the user having just dragged and dropped a file. (As an aside, [MDN's article about ways to get access to an 'entry' object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API) link to further detailed articles disclosing that each of them are experimental and to not use them in a production site.)

Is there a cross-browser compatible way to get access to the FileSystem object on-demand? Or is this a technology that has too many bugs to be useful?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Having the same problem - the documentation for the File and Directory Entries API is all over the place. I'm still not sure exactly what it does and which parts are supported in which browsers.